# What this mean !$var PERL?

Tags: perl

I get some code It works but don't understan this part !$dump_done...

```
my $dump_done = 0; 
foreach my $line(keys %results){ 
    if ($results{$line} == 1 and !$dump_done) { 
         print Dump($post); 
         $dump_done = 1; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: if you print `$post` first time, value of `$dump_done = 1` become 1. and after that, value `!$dump_one` become 0. On next time your condition will be `false` forever.

Answer (score 7):

`!` is the [Logical NOT operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Not). It will return the negation of `$dump_done`. If `$dump_done` contains `0`, the negation will give you `1`:

```
my $dump_done = 0; 
print !$dump_done;   # Prints 1
```

This is valid, because in `Perl` any non-zero value is considered `true` and `0` is considered `false`.

You can try out this snippet:

```
if (5) {
    print "Hello";   # Will be executed.
}
```

Comment: But why in this example print Dump($post);  only one time?

Comment: @user2087116. Because inside `if`, you did `$dump_done = 1;`, after which your `if` will not run again, as `!$dump_done` will be `0` now. And then since you never changed it's value inside the `for` loop, so it would be `0` always, and it prints only once.

Comment: @darch. Yeah you are right. I guessed that would be like that.

Answer (score 2):

The `!` character in most programming languages stands for *NOT*, it's the *negation*.

If the value of your variable `$dump_done` is still zero, when you test `$dump_done` it will returns *FALSE* (0). If you *negate* this expression, you get a *TRUE* expression (!= 0).

See [Truth and Falsehood](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=495975)

Comment: But why in this example print Dump($post); only one time?